# Can't print object, despite _str_ method in a class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I defined the method `_str_` in my `Book` class with attributes `title` and `author`:

```
def _str_(self):
    book_line = "{title} by {author}".format(title=self.title, author=self.author)
    return book_line
```

Now, when I create an instance of this class (say `book1`), assign values to the attributes (`'title1'`, `'author1'`) and try to print my object, Python fails to return `book_line`.

Instead, I get this annoying output `<\_main\_.Book object at 0x02BC9A30>`. On the other hand, when I do `book1._str_()`, it does return the `book_line`.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need two underscores for "magic" methods. It should be:

```
def __str__(self):

     #stuff
```

A single underscore it used to denote a "private" (or semi-private) method.

A double underscore invokes name mangling. Usually used to prevent overriding a method in a subclass.

If you had some class `Foo`:

```
class Foo:

   def __bar(self): pass
```

This method would be `_Foo__bar`

And, magic methods use double underscores on *both* sides of the method name.

Comment: Great, thanks! I am pretty new to it. By the way, why didn't Python consider it as a mistake then when I ran the script?

Comment: because `_str_` is a perfectly valid function name. Python doesn’t know that you mean '`__str__`'

Comment: It's still a valid method name, so it's not technically an "error" just a typographical mistake.

Comment: Of course, it makes perfect sense. Thanks for your time.